# Why my users defined countdown() function cannot hit the return?

Tags: python

First, the following is my function.

```
def countdown(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
```

Second, when I call countdown(0), the result is as below.

```
>>> countdown(0)
0.0
```

It means, since 0 <= 0 is true, then do if statement return 0.0.

Next, when I call countdown(3), the result is.

```
>>> countdown(3)
3
2
1
```

But I expectation is

```
>>> countdown(3)
3
2
1
0.0
```

My question is, why countdown(3) does not return 0.0?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You run your code from command line?

Comment: The last statement of the function body was probaly meant to be `return countdown(n-1)`

Comment: I try your code with both python 2.x and python 3.x and in both case countdown(0.0) produce no output. Whtn you pass 0.0 to your function condition 0.0 <= 0 == true and function just return 0.0, without printing it.

Comment: You're `return`-ing `0.0`, not `print`-ing it. So why would you expect it to be printed? You probably meant to `print(0.0)` instead of `return 0.0`...

Comment: as @AntonKovalenko has mentioned, you should return a value in both cases:
`def countdown(n):
     print n
     if n <= 0:
         return 0.0
     else:
         return countdown(n-1)`

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer. May be the OP should always print 0.0 instead of always returning it. Given his expectations for REPL output, it's either like @twalberg said or like Pynchia said.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping.@ Anton Kovalenko, kvorobiev, twalberg and Pynchia And could you please tell me what does REPL means? Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Your notion of *result* mixes up two different things:

- something printed by a function, as a side-effect.
- something returned by a function, which gets printed by REPL when you call the function in the interactive interpreter, but doesn't get printed otherwise (e.g. if you run the whole program with the python interpreter invoked from the shell).

In your first example, `countdown(0)` doesn't print anything, but REPL prints the value returned by `countdown(0)`, which is 0.0.

In your second example, `countdown(3)` ends up calling `countdown(2)`, and so on... but the *value* from `countdown(0)` is lost: that's because `countdown(1)` calls `countdown(0)` for side-effect only, not returning anything (which is equivalent to returning `None`).

There are two ways to make `countdown` match your expectations, when calling it in REPL:

- `return countdown(n-1)` as a final statement;
- `print 0.0` instead of returning it in the first `if` branch.

These two variants *look* the same when run in REPL, but in fact they are  different (see the first paragraph above).

Comment: Thank you Sir. And I would love to tell you my understanding to your answer, could you please help me to tell whether I am right or not? My understanding is, IN THE FIRST countdown(0), the flow of execution goes, main function calls countdown( ), and since n=0, then 0.0 returns to main function. Thus I get a 0.0 printed out. IN THE SECOND countdown(3) goes, and since countdown(0) is finally called by countdown(1), then the 0.0 returns to countdown(1), but not to main function. Thus I cannot get 0.0 printed.  Am I right? And what do you mean by REPL? Thank you very much, have a good day.

Comment: Yes, you're right. REPL is a well-known abbreviation for Read-Eval-Print Loop (that's what any interactive Python console does for you: Reads a statement, Evaluates it and Prints the result, all in a Loop). The most important thing here is understanding when your program prints things itself, and when python's REPL prints things for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't want to use `return`. Instead of `return` use `print()`.

So your function should be:

```
def countdown(n):
    if n <= 0:
        print(0.0)
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
```

Or simplified (but a bit weird):

```
def countdown(n):
    print(max(0.0, n))
    if n > 0:
        countdown(n - 1)
```

As answer to your question I will say: it's because Python shell prints returned object and code doesn't.

Make program which executes your `countdown` function with value 0 or less.

It won't print anything.
So it's best to **not** use `return` for printing things.

**EDIT:**

You should use `return` when you (or anyone else) wants to use that value.

Example:

```
def SUM(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

If you want to use SUM of three numbers you could just write `a = SUM(3, 4, 5)`.

If you used `print` instead of `return` a would be None.

Also I think almost all shells prints returned value.
Return printing is like printing values without `print`, *e.g.:* if you write `5 + 1` in shell it would print 6, but if it's in function/program it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir. And I have another question. Are things returned, by **return** statement, to main function will be printed out?  And whether those things, **return** to main function, will be printed out or not depends on shell?

Comment: @jiaru0123 I updated my answer. Also it would be good if you up vote our answers (I find them both correct) and mark better one.